# NodaTime with Fakes throws TypeInitializationException, but doesn't without Fakes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I want to Shim the NodaTime `SystemClock.GetCurrentInstant()` method. Therefore I created a UnitTest in VisualStudio 2017 (also tried in 2015). I added the NodaTime package through Nuget Package Explorer to the UnitTest project. Afterwards I did a right click on the NodaTime assembly and pressed *Add Fakes Assembly*.

I wrote a small piece of code, which threw an *TypeInitializationException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program*.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NodaTime;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var a = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("Europe/Amsterdam");
        }
    }
}
```

This gave me the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'TzdbHolder' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DefaultHolder' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbZone1970Location..ctor(Int32 latitudeSeconds, Int32 longitudeSeconds, IEnumerable`1 countries, String zoneId, String comment)
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbZone1970Location.Read(IDateTimeZoneReader reader)
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.IO.TzdbStreamData.Builder.HandleZone1970LocationsField(TzdbStreamField field)
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.IO.TzdbStreamData.<>c.<.cctor>b__24_6(Builder builder, TzdbStreamField field)
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.IO.TzdbStreamData.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.DefaultHolder.LoadDefaultDataSource()
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.DefaultHolder..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.get_Default()
   at NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.TzdbHolder..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.get_Tzdb()
   at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\**snip**\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 16
```

I debugged the NodaTime source code and it was going bad on a foreach loop on a List. When I removed that foreach loop, the code was running fine. When I added a foreachloop over a List of ints (see code below) the exception came back.

```
foreach(var i in List<int> {1,2,3}) {}
```

When I changed it into a normal for loop, the exception disappeared.

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3};
for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
}
```

So it has something to do with the `foreach` loop and a `List`. For anyone interested, the code can be found on [NodaTime's GitHub repository](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/TimeZones/TzdbZone1970Location.cs#L95-L99)

Anyway, when I remove the Fakes assembly I generated at the beginning of this post, the test executes and passes. But hey, I wanted to Shim the `SystemClock.GetCurrentInstant()` method I mentioned earlier.

This is not a bug in NodaTime, but I think this is a bug in VisualStudio Test Runner. Google said 'no' when I searched for this behavior of Visual Studio. I tried also to run the test with Nunit, that succeeded, but in Nunit it is not possible to use `ShimsContext` :-(.

Do you guys know what is going on here? Just want to check with you before I report this to the MSFT VS team.

Thank you all for helping me tracking down this bug.

**Program versions:**

- Visual Studio 15.2 (26430.15) Release (Enterprise edition)
- .NET Framework 4.7.02046
- Fakes (latest shipped with Visual Studio 15.2)
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (updated to latest)
- ReSharper 2017.1.3 (tried also without ReSharper enabled)
- NodaTime 2.2.0 (latest stable from NuGet, also tried compiling from the GitHub repo)

Comment: `Google said 'no' when I searched for this behavior of Visual Studio.` What does this sentence mean?

Comment: "I want to Shim the NodaTime SystemClock.GetCurrentInstant() method." You shouldn't. You should inject an `IClock`, using `SystemClock.Instance` for your production code, and `FakeClock` from `NodaTime.Testing` for your tests - that's what it's there for. Obviously this shouldn't be happening though...

Comment: @mjwills it was a reference to "Computer says no" http://youtu.be/AJQ3TM-p2QI . In other words I couldn't find anything about this problem with the help of Google :-)

Comment: It's probably worth including the versions of everything involved - Visual Studio, .NET, Noda Time, Fakes etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am aware there is a NodaTime.Testing package. But if I'm right the Fakes Framework should work as well. All of our code testing is done with stubs and shims from Fakes Framework. So our preference goes to use Fakes.

Comment: It seems very odd to me to use a  harder-to-test approach even when there's a testable approach available. I'd use intrusive things like Fakes only when you're in naturally hard-to-test situations.

Comment: @JonSkeet fair enough. I'm going to use the `NodaTime.Testing` library for now as I don't have any other options. In my opinion it was easier to shim just 1 property instead of changing all the code to accept injecting an IClock instance. Still this is a bug that should be fixed by Microsoft, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to fork the NodaTime, please add to your CSProj:

```
   <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Nodatime\TimeZones\Tzdb.nzd" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Reference:
Nodatime.csproj